# Solve system of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have four polynomials with four unknowns $x_{1},x_{2},y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ as following
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
m_{1} + m_{2}x_{1} + (m_{5} + m_{6}x_{2})y_{1} + (m_{3}+m_{4}x_{1})y_{2} ==0 \\ 
n_{1} + n_{2}x_{1} + (n_{3} + n_{4}x_{1})y_{1} + n_{5}x_{2}y_{2} ==0 \\
x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} = 1\\
y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2} = 1\\
\end{array},
\right. 
$$
where $m_{1}$, $m_{2}$, $m_{3}$, $m_{4}$, $m_{5}$, $m_{6}$, $n_{1}$, $n_{2}$, $n_{3}$, $n_{4}$ and $n_{5}$ are unknown real values.
Does anyone know there is someway to eliminate any of the three variables, and then get an equation with only one variable. I use Mathematica, it compute a long time... and I havent got it yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Seek for  *resultant of *$n+1$ polynomials in $n$ variables (Macaulay's resultant).

Comment: Rewrite it in vector form considering $u = (x_1, x_2)$ and $v=(y_1, y_2)$ this should make it more clear to you